# Appending to the list outside function in python not changing the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, global

```
lst_val = []
def func():
    for value in any_list:
        global lst_val 
        lst_val .append(value)
```

I'm using the above code to append values to a list outside of function. But, it is still showing as empty list. How can I modify the list within a function?

Comment: what is `dict[]` ? if it is `dict()` so the loop will not run since it is empty dict. Also are you calling the function?

Comment: actually, it can be any list. I'm facing issue in updating the list using append. The for loop is running fine otherwise.

Comment: Please provide reproducible code which we can run and check, this way it is easier to tell the issue.

Comment: Have you _called_ the function `func()`?

Comment: As a side note, you should have called `lst_val.extend(any_list)` to accomplish the same goal. No loop needed.

Comment: If you have made edits to your original post, please indicate that to avoid confusion. Also, please indicate whether your problem has solved when it does.

Comment: What is `any_list`. If `any_list` is defined but empty, then the for loop would not run

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try the following code.

```
lst_val = []
class Sample:
def func(any_list):
    global lst_val
    for value in any_list:
        lst_val.append(value)

    return lst_val


Sample.func([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(lst_val)
```

Comment: Why did you add a pointless class... `Sample` (with incorrect syntax, btw)

Answer (score 0):

You just need **any_list** without square brackets. If you call the function, I believe you'll get a syntax error.

Answer (score -2):

The issue seems to be that nothing is being returned by the function which is why you're getting "None" Give this a try:

```
dict1 = [1,2,3]

lst_val = []

def func():
        for value in dict1:
            global lst_val
            lst_val.append(value)
    return lst_val

print(func())
print(lst_val)

// func()  returns: [1, 2, 3]
// lst_val returns: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: There is no need to return a global variable. The OP's problem is elsewhere.

Comment: even if that's the case, lets completely disregard the fact that it produced the desired results and OP could take it out if needed.

Comment: The OP's code *already* produces the desired results. Furthermore, the OP mentioned nothing about `None`, rather, they mentioned that the list remained empty.

Comment: printing the result of func() returned None which is where I got that, I see @DYZ pointed out that it was more than likely due to the function not being called which worked for me as well so I was wrong.